# Error searching to find hardware freezing issue

Tags: windows, freeze, hardware-failure

I came home to find my computer frozen at the screensaver.

I forced a restart, and it froze at the regular Windows start up. Sometimes it would launch completely, and then freeze pretty soon after. Other times it would be at the Windows loading graphic.

I ran in safe mode and it froze on `crcdisk.sys` every single time.

I reformatted to rule out software issues. That did not fix the issue. During the Windows installation it freezes, usually when the installation has started.

I bought and plugged in a new hard drive, gave my computer a good dusting and attempted to install Windows again. That did not help either; now it freezes as soon as the Windows installation window opens.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Since you said "gave your computer a good dusting", I am guessing that your CPU is overheating due to congestion.  REMOVE the heatsink and fan off the CPU, clean thoroughly.  Put a touch of thermal goo on the CPU before putting the heatsink back on.  After connecting it and starting it back up, inspect ALL the fans to make sure they're running.  Clean the video card's fan equally.

Comment: I keep Speed Fan running regularly and I wouldn't say it was an overheating issue. The most recent temperature I saw wasn't low but nowhere close to an overheating temperature.

Answer (score 0):

If you get CRC errors (which the crash in `crcdisk.sys` indicates), there is a good possibility that your RAM might be defective.
Download [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org) and let it run at least 5 passes to see if anything comes up.

Comment: I can't even get into windows to download anything, let alone let it run.

Comment: @Laura You have access to some other computer, right? Otherwise you wouldn't be posting here. So [download Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso) on that. It's an ISO that you burn to a CD and boot from, so you don't need to boot into Windows on your own computer.

Comment: I haven't done the memtest run yet, which I am in the process of burning now. But after removing 1 stick of ram at a time, it still freezes just the same either of them in.

Comment: Thats strange, maybe something on your mainboard is broken, maybe the lanes to the memory or the CPU as this behavior is what one would expect if RAM is corrupt. Maybe also the HDD cables. But you'll find that out if you run Memtest+ as it runs directly from the RAM and does not use the hard disk. If memtest does not show any errors download `UltimateBootCD` and perform a check on your HDD